# converting a tree to a data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tree-traversal

Before I write it myself, I wonder if there is a function that already does that:

I have a tree structure, implemented as a nested list of lists. each node has some internal data (such as its name), and a list of sons, which in turn contain some node data and a further list of sons, etc. The tree is complete, that is, all branches are full and of the same length.

I want to traverse the tree to create a data.frame in which each row contains
the full data on a branch of the tree, with all the branches included

so for a tree with 2 level-1 nodes below the root (named a, b) with each having two sons (named c,d for node a, and e,f for noe b) my data.frame should look like:

```
## root a  c
## root a  d
## root b  e
## root b  f
```

the list structure probably look like:

```
tree = list(list(name = "a", sons = list(list(name = "c"),list(name="d"))),
            list(name = "b", sons = list(list(name = "e"),list(name="f"))))
```

traversing is basic, I can write it myself, but hate to invent existing stuff

so is there something out there?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `melt` (from "reshape2") to see whether it gets you near your target (I haven't yet, but I know it has a method for `list`s too).

Comment: It does have a method for list, but apparently it doesn't work well for nested structures. I tried it just now and got something very odd.

Comment: Could you do something along the lines of `t(sapply(tree, unlist, recursive=TRUE))` and then reshape it to get end result - not sure how well it will work for more complex structures

Comment: I just used `melt` on a tree-like structure, and as long as you know how to name your columns, it works perfectly.  Granted, my tree-like structure was along the lines of:

independent variable -> group A or B of dependent variables -> dependent variable -> time lag of dependent variable

Answer (score 0):

OK - sorry for answering my own question.
After giving it more thoughts I wrote a rather generic code. it assumes a structure that contains nested lists in such a way that at each level you need to extract certain fields, and the follow a field that contains a list of descendents elements. The assumption is that all nodes at the same level looks the same in terms of fields to extract and where to look for descendents. Under these assumptions, the traversal can be encoded using three parameters:

root - the complete data 
extract - a list of field names. each list entry is a vector of field names/indices about data to be extracted at a given level
follow - a list of field names/indices, which tells us where to look for the list of descendents at each level.

the code goes:

```
tt2df = function(root,extract = 1,follow=2,level=1) {
if(is.null(root)) return(NULL)
n= length(extract)
if(n==0) return(NULL)
if(level>n) return(NULL)
if (length(follow)!=n) stop("extract and follow do not match")
vals = unlist(root[extract[[level]]])
sons = tryCatch(root[[follow[[level]]]],error=function(s) return(NULL))
if(n==level) {
    return(data.frame(t(vals)))
}
temp = data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(1:length(sons), function(x) {
        son = sons[[x]]
        res = tt2df(son,extract,follow,level+1)
        nm = paste(follow[[level]],level,sep=".")
        res[[nm]] = x
        return(res)
        })))
for(x in names(vals)) {
nx = x
if(x %in% names(temp))
nx = paste(x,level,sep=".")
temp[[nx]] = vals[x]
}
return(temp)
}
```

I haven't checked it thoroughly but it works for a few examples I have, some are rather complex. One can also make it more beautiful/efficient. I welcome comments/improvements

I find it especially useful to traverse parsed JSON files.
Feel free to use it at your own risk. but let me know if you find it useful/problematic

Comment: I guess, there are simpler ways. `data.frame(matrix(unlist(tree), nrow=length(tree), byrow=T))`